How to deal with struct errors in Rust?
I am new to Rust. I am using the sqlite crate and have this:
connection.execute("CREATE TABLE my_table (foo, bar);").unwrap();

If I run this and my_table already exists, this "raises" an error, as expected:
called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error { code: Some(1), message: Some("table my_table already exists") }

I want to "catch" this specific case, and just ignore it, but keep "raising" the error in any other case. I've been reading the Recoverable Errors with Result in the Rust Book, and there is an example to deal with enum errors. However, errors in the sqlite crate are structs instead (doc). Though for an experienced rustacean this may be obvious, I am struggling on how to deal with this. I wrote this piece of code:
match connection.execute("CREATE TABLE my_table (foo, bar);") {
            Ok(whatever) => "fine",
            Err(error) => {
                match error.code {
                    Some(1) => {
                        match error.message {
                            Some(ref msg) => {
                                if msg == "table my_table already exists" {
                                    "ok"
                                } else {
                                    panic!("Something happened {:?}", error);
                                }
                            }
                            _ => panic!("Something happened {:?}", error),
                        }
                    }
                    _ => panic!("Something happened {:?}", error),
                }
            }
        };

which seems to work, but it feels to me that is not the way to go, because of how extensive it is and I have many replicated panic!(...) lines. Is this the way I am supposed to deal with the error? Is there a more idiomatic way?

Seems like the XY problem: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS

Actually yes, that is a simpler solution to this specific example, but I would like to know how to handle any alike situation from the Rust side.

Unless this is a very strange SQL implementation, the error message to creating table my_table will never say that the table particles_system already exists.

@RichardNeumann forgot to change it when posting here, will fix it now. Thanks for pointing it out.

As @Ry- said, the correct fix is to use CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS. But to improve your Rust-fu:
match connection.execute("CREATE TABLE my_table (foo, bar);") {
    Ok(_) => "fine",
    Err(sqlite::Error {
        code: Some(1),
        message: Some(message),
    }) if message == "table my_table already exists" => "ok",
    Err(error) => panic!("Something happened: {error:?}"),
}


Another way is to deconstruct the Result with if let and then propagate it with the ? operator if its code is not 1. (Assuming code 1 is always "table already exists")
This should be helpful if your logic isn't part of main and you don't want to handle errors directly.
// Deconstruct to get err
if let Err(err) = connection.execute("CREATE TABLE my_table (foo, bar);") {
    // Deconstruct to get code, ignore message
    if let sqlite::Error { code: Some(code), message: _ } = err {
        if code != 1 {
            // Propagate error
            Err(err)?    
        }
    }
}

